# Mantis: Change default columns in mail when a ticket is closed

Tags: mantis

I'd love to change automatic mantis issue mail. I'd love, for instance, remove reproducibility, priority and severity fields.

Is tha possbile? I need to edit a php? Which one?

Answer (score 0):

For now this is not configurable, so I suggest you file an enhancement request or add your comment to an existing one on the [MantisBT bug tracker](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/).

You can also edit [core/email.php](https://github.com/mantisbt/mantisbt/blob/78c545fec84b6705b05fdff9a6bad3f07a01de4e/core/email_api.php#L1234) and patch the `email_format_bug_message` function, but that will get you in trouble when you're going to update.